# C\C++ - win32: how avoid flickers with transparent controls\child controls?

Tags: c++, winapi

i have read several tutorials\threads(even from here) and i didn't get the property answer :(
for not draw the window backgound i must do(make the control\child control transparent):

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        {
            return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
        }
        break;
```

until here fine.

- for avoid flicker i must use Double-Buffering way and the parent window must have the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style.

if the control isn't transparent, the flicker is out. when it's not transparent, the image is drawed 1 above other. if i use the FillRect() on WM_PAINT the control is 'clean' and then show the new image... but isn't transparent :(
what can anyone advice me?

Comment: We can, at present, only guess at what you want to achieve, and what your code is. Double buffering may not be needed. Probably not if you get everything right. But there's too much left to guesswork.

Comment: Are you trying to make a *partially transparent* control? Can you provide screenshots or something that we can use to determine what you might be doing wrong?

Comment: when i use the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style, why the control isn't clean, before re-draw it?
heres the image problem: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=C3EF456E15C8DEB6&id=c3ef456e15c8deb6!1273&v=3